# Получить заголовок страницы webview

Tags: java, android, webview

Как получить заголовок страницы webview?

Answer (score 4):

Если вы хотите получить заголовок загруженной страницы, то поставьте слушатель на `WebView`. В метод `onPageFinished` передаётся сам `WebView` и ссылка страницы, которая была загружена. Из `WebView` можно получить `title` с помощью метода `getTitle()`.

Например, вот тут заголовок страницы поместится в `ActionBar` или в `Toolbar`

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        MainActivity.this.setTitle(view.getTitle());
}});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

   webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String sTitle) {
                    super.onReceivedTitle(view, sTitle);

                    // sTitle - собственно тайтл страницы, сохранить его куда-то
                }
            });
```

Или так:

```
 WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mwebview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           // заголовок страницы
            view.getTitle(); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Хпхахах одновременно ответили ))

Comment: Я просто писал долго